# Stuck on how to find QueryDSL predicate in spring data app

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, querydsl

I have a problem in querying some data, I will explain my problem briefly and set an example for clarification

I use Spring data, QueryDSL and MySQL.

I want to query like this in queryDSL method. A specific example is just a simple example to give an idea.

Say for example, there are two tables Employee and Certificate. Relation between two is ONE (Employee) to MANY (Certificate)

Following are tables

```
Employee (id, first_name, last_name);
Certificate (id, name, date, fk_emp);
```

Following are the entities,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
class Employee {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
  private String firstName;

  @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
  private String lastName;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Certificate> certificates = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CERTIFICATE")
class Certificate {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name = "CERTIFICATE_NAME")
  private String certificateName;

  @Column(name = "DATE")
  private Date date;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "REF_EMPLOYEE")
  private Employee employee;
}
```

**What should the QueryDSL predicate be for
Returning all employees with name contains (in first_name and last_name) and from that result whose certification between date 22-12-2014 to 22-12-2015**

**At the same time, I want to obtain all employees who do not have any certificates**

example of results:

```
+----+--------------------+---------------------+--------+
| id | name               | date                | fk_emp |
+----+--------------------+---------------------+--------+
|  1 | FirstName LastName | 2014-02-01 00:00:00 |  11111 |
+----+--------------------+---------------------+--------+
|  2 | FirstName LastName | 2014-03-01 00:00:00 |  null  |
+----+--------------------+---------------------+--------+
|  3 | FirstName LastName | 2014-04-01 00:00:00 |        |
+----+--------------------+---------------------+--------+
|  5 | FirstName LastName | 2014-05-01 00:00:00 |        |
+----+--------------------+---------------------+--------+
| 12 | FirstName LastName | 2014-06-01 00:00:00 |  25555 |
+----+--------------------+---------------------+--------+
| 13 | FirstName LastName | 2014-07-01 00:00:00 |  78888 |
+----+--------------------+---------------------+--------+
| 16 | FirstName LastName | 2014-08-01 00:00:00 |  null  |
+----+--------------------+---------------------+--------+
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Native JPQL Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE A
LEFT JOIN CERTIFICATE B ON A.ID = B.REF_EMPLOYEE AND DATE BETWEEN CAST('2014-12-22' AS DATE) AND CAST('2015-12-22' AS DATE);
```

**Querydsl join variant:**

```
query.from(employee)
    .leftJoin(employee.certificates, certificate)
    .on(certificate.date.between('from_date', 'to_date'))
    .list(employee);
```

Note: Date format can be different here and please change according to your need

Comment: At the same time, I want to obtain all employees who do not have any certificates

Comment: Left join will pull all the employees from Employee table i.e., it will pull both "employees with certificate" and "employees without certificate". Please try to run the query in mysql and frame it according to your need. Kindly let me know of any help.

Comment: I have a error in line 3: Cannot resolve method 'on' in 'JPQLQuery'

Comment: on() has been introduced since QueryDsl 3.0.0 version.
I'd suggest to upgrade your version to 3.0.0 when you use older. Also, did you try native sql query in the meantime?

Comment: how can i use the native sql query because i try added the request in @Query(""); but not work

Comment: @Query(nativeQuery =true, value = "YOUR NATIVE  QUERY")